# Determine non-overlapping locations with Perl

Tags: perl, combinatorics

I have a collection of locations--here is an example of the data structure.

```
my $locations =
{
  loc_1 =>
  {
    start => 1,
    end   => 193,
  },
  loc_2 =>
  {
    start => 180,
    end   => 407,
  },
  loc_3 =>
  {
    start => 329,
    end   => 684,
  },
  loc_4 =>
  {
    start => 651,
    end   => 720,
  },
};
```

What is the best way to determine every possible combination of non-overlapping locations? The answer for this example would look something like this. Keep in mind there may be one or more locations, and these locations may or may not overlap.

```
my $non_overlapping_locations =
[
  {
    loc_1 =>
    {
      start => 1,
      end   => 193,
    },
    loc_3 =>
    {
      start => 329,
      end   => 684,
    },
  },
  {
    loc_1 =>
    {
      start => 1,
      end   => 193,
    },
    loc_4 =>
    {
      start => 651,
      end   => 720,
    },
  },
  {
    loc_2 =>
    {
      start => 180,
      end   => 407,
    },
    loc_4 =>
    {
      start => 651,
      end   => 720,
    },
  }
];
```

**Update**: `ysth`'s response helped me see a flaw in my wording. I guess I'm not interested in //every possible// combination of non-overlapping locations, I'm only interested in the solutions that are not subsets of other solutions.

Comment: Just a thought... would a better output be:
`( [qw(loc_1 loc_3)], [qw(loc_1 loc_4)], [qw(loc_2 loc_4)] )` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely more concise, and I guess it doesn't make it any more difficult to access the data I need. Good suggestion.

Comment: your example only allows pairs of non-overlapping regions, but are you looking for arbitrarily large sets of non-overlapping regions as possible outputs?

Comment: @Dancrumb, outside of this example, there is no guarantee that there will only be two regions in a solution. So yes you're right, I'm looking for solutions that may be much larger--all of them, assuming they are not subsets of another solution (thanks to @ysth for helping me clarify that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $locations =
{
  loc_1 =>
  {
    start => 1,
    end   => 193,
  },
  loc_2 =>
  {
    start => 180,
    end   => 407,
  },
  loc_3 =>
  {
    start => 329,
    end   => 684,
  },
  loc_4 =>
  {
    start => 651,
    end   => 720,
  },
};
my $non_overlapping_locations = [];
my @locations = sort keys %$locations;

get_location_combinations( $locations, $non_overlapping_locations, [], @locations );

use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($non_overlapping_locations);

sub get_location_combinations {
    my ($locations, $results, $current, @remaining) = @_;

    if ( ! @remaining ) {
        if ( not_a_subset_combination( $results, $current ) ) {
            push @$results, $current;
        }
    }
    else {
        my $next = shift @remaining;
        if (can_add_location( $locations, $current, $next )) {
            get_location_combinations( $locations, $results, [ @$current, $next ], @remaining );
        }
        get_location_combinations( $locations, $results, [ @$current ], @remaining );
    }
}

sub can_add_location {
    my ($locations, $current, $candidate) = @_;

    # not clear if == is an overlap; modify to use >=  and <= if so.
    0 == grep $locations->{$candidate}{end} > $locations->{$_}{start} && $locations->{$candidate}{start} < $locations->{$_}{end}, @$current;
}

sub not_a_subset_combination {
    my ($combinations, $candidate) = @_;

    for my $existing (@$combinations) {
        my %candidate;
        @candidate{@$candidate} = ();
        delete @candidate{@$existing};
        if ( 0 == keys %candidate ) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

A relatively simple optimization would be to sort @locations by start and then end and pre-calculate and store in a hash (or just in $locations->{foo}) for each location how many of the following locations conflict with that location.  Then in the can_add... case, splice that number off of @remaining before recursing.

Or pre-calculate for each location a hash of all following locations that conflict and strip them all out with a grep before recursing.  (Though with that approach, having remaining be a hash begins to make more sense.)

Update: another approach to a solution would be to build up a tree of locations to exclude, where leaves represent solutions and inner nodes represent combinations that still have conflicts; the top node is all locations, and each node has children that represent removing one of the remaining conflicting locations that's greater (in some arbitrary ordering scheme) than the location removed by the parent node (if any).

Comment: For the example above, I purposefully didn't include the solutions that contain just 0 or 1 locations. So this response answers my question, although I see now that I must slightly reword my question! I don't know how to generalize this, though.

Comment: The default behavior should be to include all locations, only excluding locations if they overlap.

Comment: @Daniel Standage: that's completely inconsistent with "find all combinations".  Or do you mean to never include a solution that is a subset of another solution?

Comment: It was indeed inconsistent, and I hoped my edit made that clear. However, I think your wording is even clearer: `do not include a solution that is a subset of another solution`. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Standage: modified to remove subsets

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a CS guy, so I'm not down with all of the best algorithms, but I wonder if there's a better approach than:

```
my @location_keys = keys %{$locations};
while (my $key_for_checking = (shift @location_keys) {
    foreach my $key_to_compare (@location_keys) {
        if ( do_not_overlap($locations->{$key_for_checking}, 
                            $locations->{$key_to_compare} ) {
            add_to_output($key_for_checking, $key_to_compare);
        }
    }
}
```

With `do_not_overlap` and `add_to_output` suitable defined.

If you're wondering about checking for overlap... that's pretty straightforward.
A and B do not overlap if:

```
( (A->start < B->start) && (A->end < B->start) ) ||
( (A->start > B->end)   && (A->end > B->end) )
```

You may need to tweak depending on whether a shared boundary constitutes an overlap. Also, you can simplify this if you know whether A and B are sorted in some way (either by start or by end)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question I'm asking. It would find that `loc_1` does not overlap with `loc_3` and `loc_4`, so it would group these three locations together. That is incorrect, however, since `loc_3` and `loc_4` overlap, which we don't want.

Comment: Your overlap function is complicated too: 
`b.end > a.start && b.start < a.end` would suffice.

Comment: @Daniel, it wouldn't. It only ever compares pairs of locations, so it would not generate a triplet of loc_1, loc_3 and loc_4. You can see that each call to `do_not_overlap` only uses 2 locations and `add_to_output` uses the same 2

Comment: Thanks @Konerak; So, the 'non-overlap' version would be `b.end =< a.start || b.start => a.end`... which if we consider a boundary match to be an overlap and swap variable names, is `a.end < b.start || a.start > b.end`, which matches what I have, once we remove the other expressions, which are self evidently true, since `a.end < b.start` implies `a.start < b.start`.
I think my expression is much more explicit, however, for those who prefer conciseness, yours is a +1

Answer (score 1):

First i would gather all the individual points (the start and end of each location), sort them and keep them in a list. In your case that would be:

```
1,180,193,329,407,651,684,720.
```

For each interval in that list find out how many segments are overlapping it. In your case this would be:

```
1, 180 -> 1
180, 193 -> 2
193, 329 -> 1
329, 407 -> 2
407, 651 -> 1
651, 684 -> 2
684, 720 -> 1
```

and loop at what segments have more than 1 (in this case there are 3). So the total number of cases is 2 x 2 x 2 = 8 solutions (you can pick only one segment maching a multi interval in a solution).

we found 2, 2, 2 (or 2, 3, 4). Keep them in an array and start from the last. Decrement it until you reach 0. When you reach 1 decrement the previous number and set the first number at the initial value minus 1.

Let's assume we have numbered the initial segments: (in this case `1,2,3,4,5,6`). The overlapping segments will have the following segments in them `[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]`. So we have 3 overlapping segments. Now we start a recursive process of choice/elimination:
At each step we are looking at an overlapping segment that has multiple segments. We iterate the choices and for each choice we do two things: eliminate from each subsequent overlapping segment the segments we didn't choose now, and force the current segment choice in each subsequent overlapping segments that have this choice as a possibility. Every segment that becomes a non overlapping will be treated as a new choice. Search for next multiple choice and recurse. Once we can't find a choice we have partial solution. We need to add to it the segments that aren't involved in any overlapping. Print it.

In this case it would go like this: First step:

```
we are here [1,2], [2,3], [3,4]:
  chose 1 -> // eliminate 2 from rest and force 1 (3 is a single choice so we do the same)
      [1], [3], [3] -> [1, 3] solution 
  chose 2 -> // eliminate 1 from the rest and force 2 (2 single choice so we do the same). 
      [2], [2], [4] -> [2, 4] solution
```

This should work properly.

Now the code implementing this (it's not the prettiest perl code around i assume but i'm really not a perl guy):

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my $locs = {
  loc_1 => {
    start => 1,
    end   => 193,
  },
  loc_2 => {
    start => 180,
    end   => 407,
  },
  loc_3 => {
    start => 329,
    end   => 684,
  },
  loc_4 => {
            start => 651,
    end   => 720,
  }
};

my (%starts, %ends);
map {
        my ($start, $end) = ($locs->{$_}->{start}, $locs->{$_}->{end});

        push @{ $starts{$start} }, $_;
        push @{ $ends{$end} }, $_;
} keys %$locs;

my @overlaps, my %tmp;

map {
        map { $tmp{$_} = 1 } @{$starts{$_}};
        map { delete $tmp{$_} } @{$ends{$_}};

        my @segs = keys %tmp;
        push @overlaps, \@segs if 1 < @segs
} sort (keys %starts, keys %ends);

sub parse_non_overlapping {
  my ($array,$pos)=($_[0], $_[1]);

  my @node = @{$array->[$pos]};
  foreach my $value ( @node ) {

    my @work = map { [@$_] } @$array;
    $work[$pos] = [ $value ];

    my ($removed, $forced) = ( {}, {$value => 1});
    map { $removed->{$_} = 1 if $_ ne $value } @node;

    my ($i, $new_pos) = (0, -1);
    for ( $i = $pos + 1; $i <= $#work; $i++ ) {
        $_ = $work[$i];

        #apply map
        @$_ = grep { not defined($removed->{$_}) } @$_;
        if ( $#$_ == 0 ) { $forced->{@$_[0]} = 1 }

        #apply force
            my @tmp = grep { defined $forced->{$_} } @$_;
        if ( $#tmp == 0 ) {
             map { $removed->{$_} = 1 if $tmp[0] ne $_ } @$_;
             @$_ = @tmp;
        }

        if ( $#$_ > 0 && $new_pos == -1 ) {
                $new_pos = $i;
        }

        $work[$i] = $_;
    }

    if ( $new_pos != -1 ) {
      parse_non_overlapping(\@work, $new_pos);
    } else {
      print Dumper \@work
       # @work has the partial solution minux completely non overlapping segments.
    }
  }
}    

parse_non_overlapping(\@overlaps, 0);
```

Comment: You've shown me how to find areas where multiple segments overlap, but `Iterate them and print them` is kind of a vague answer to `What is the best way to determine every possible combination of non-overlapping locations`.

Comment: Look now for a possible explanation. I'm thinking a little more to make sure we can avoid a combinatorial explosion.

Comment: This is as linear as it's possible i think. I'm sorry i'm not really a perl guy to build this into a solution for you.

Comment: Added a implementation of the algorithm. This should find the most comprehensive solutions.

Comment: I get duplicate loc_2 in your first result and loc_3 in your second?

Comment: yea. They should be deduplicated before printing. i got lazy :).

Answer (score 0):

(Real life intrudes - Apologies, I'll write an explanation - and get ride of those empty arrayrefs, although that's fairly trivial - later!)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
use Data::Dumper;

my $locations = {
    loc_1 => {
        start => 1,
        end   => 193,
    },
    loc_2 => {
        start => 180,
        end   => 407,
    },
    loc_3 => {
        start => 329,
        end   => 684,
    },
    loc_4 => {
        start => 651,
        end   => 720,
    },
};

my @keys = keys %$locations;

my %final;

for my $key (@keys) {
    push @{ $final{$key} }, map {
        if (   $locations->{$key}->{start} >= $locations->{$_}->{start}
            && $locations->{$key}->{start} <= $locations->{$_}->{end}
            or $locations->{$key}->{end} >= $locations->{$_}->{start}
            && $locations->{$key}->{end} <= $locations->{$_}->{end} )
        {
            ();
        }
        else {
            my $return = [ sort $key, $_ ];
            if ( any { $return ~~ $_ } @{ $final{$_} }, @{ $final{$key} } ) {
                ();
            }
            else { $return; }
        }
    } grep { $_ ne $key } keys %$locations;
}

say Dumper \%final;
```

Comment: The complexity of this is O(n^2) or i'm missing something ?

Comment: It reads as O(n^2) indeed, but it's unclear to me it's actually possible to do better.

Comment: i think the algorithm i have posted above ( pretty damn verbose ) should be lower than that. Check it out.

Comment: Lacking a CS background, my grasp of the big O notation is.. Well, it isn't. If you folk say it's O(n^2), I'll have to believe you. Hopefully real life will let go and give me a chance to implement Toader's solution.